# What is the gargantuan monster on DMG page 248?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

The giant worm-like creature in the graph.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### It's a [Purple Worm](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/purple-worm)

A gargantuan monstrosity you can find under 'P' in the Monster Manual